# How to get the list of jars downloaded from a specific repository out of many defined in pom.xml

Tags: pom.xml

I have the following repositories defined in my pom.xml.

```
 <repositories>
<repository>
  <id>spring-maven-release</id>
  <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
  <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
  <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
  <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>

<repository>
  <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
  <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
  <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
</repository>

<repository>
  <id>xxxx-repo.snapshot</id>
  <name>iGV Snapshot Repository</name>
  <url>http://mavenrepo.XXXX.com/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Is there a way to know the jars that are downloaded from http://mavenrepo.XXXX.com/maven2 in the above pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Yes you can check by following steps:
Right click on project explorer folder n click on new.
Click on others,select maven new project.
Click next,choose default work-space.
Now you can see list of archetypes these are nothing but dependencies that comes with maven.

Comment: Hi Palak,Thanks for replying.Actually I am building my application from console.I wanted to know the list of JARS that are downloaded from a specific repository(marked above) from the list of repositories that are defined in the pom.xml

Comment: @souvikchakraborty-did you add environment variable m2?